# Overriding something tagged !important that applies last? (If even possible)

Tags: css, reddit

I was recently mad a Moderator for a subreddit because I can use CSS.  Here is the problem...  Reddit Enhancement Suite, an extension for web-browsers is (At least I am pretty sure, after some testing) applied after my style sheet.  It has code block that changes the background  color of a selected item, and that line is marked !important.  I've tried adding an !important tag to my sheet and the parent class (If that is what they are called.  I am more familiar with OOP than Web Programming) background color lines, to no prevail.

Here is my current non-working code:

```
.RES-keyNav-activeElement, .commentarea .RES-keyNav-activeElement .md, .commentarea .RES-keyNav-activeElement.entry .noncollapsed 
{
background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55) !important;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
.RES-keyNav-activeElement
{
background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55) !important;
}
```

Anything you guys come up with would be great!

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Just chain some more selectors to it and it will be more specific.

Comment: Yeah, you need to use a more specific selector than the selector that is overriding your styles, such as #container .parent .RES-keyNav-activeElement

Comment: Important will still follow CSS precedence. An inline important will triumph all.

Answer (score 2):

After some fiddling around with it myself today, I found a solution.

The following will affect listings on the front page of a subreddit:

```
.entry.likes.RES-keyNav-activeElement.lcTagged
{
background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55) !important;
}
```

And the following will affect the comments within a post:

```
.entry.likes.RES-keyNav-activeElement,
.commentarea .RES-keyNav-activeElement.entry.likes .noncollapsed,
.commentarea .RES-keyNav-activeElement.entry.likes .md
{
background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55) !important;
}
```

As mentioned elsewhere, the key is to be more specific than RES is being.

Comment: BTW, just `.entry.RES-keyNav-activeElement` also works for posts.